# shell script to list file names alone in a directory & rename it

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell

I'm new to scripting concept.. I have a requirement to rename multiple files in a directory like `filename.sh.x` into `filename.sh`

First I tried to get the file names in a particular directory.. so i followed the below scripting code

```
for entry in PathToThedirectory/*sh.x
do
   echo $entry
done
```

& the above code listed down all the file names with full path..

But my expected o/p is : to get file names alone like `abc.sh.x`, 
so that I can proceed with the split string mechanism to perform rename 
operation easily...
help me to solve this ... Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `rename` command and its regex feature.

Comment: This question has not got anything to do with C . Remove that tag, please.

Comment: I got it.. thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach trying to follow OP suggestions:

```
for i in my/path/*.py.x
do
    basename=$(basename "$i")
    mv my/path/"$basename" my/path/"${basename%.*}"
done
```

And maybe, you can simplify it:

```
for i in my/path/*.py.x
do
    mv "$i" "${i%.*}";
done
```

Documentation regarding this kind of operation (parameter expansion): https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

In particular:

> ${parameter%word} : The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted

So, `${i%.*}` means:

- Take `$i`
- Match `.*` at the end of its value (`.` being a literal character)
- Remove the shortest matching pattern

Comment: Why "maybe"? The second solution looks much cleaner to me, doesn't require external tools and is probably faster.

Comment: Well, the first one sounds more like what the OP was asking for (`get file names alone`) ... but yes you are right.

Comment: Ah, yes, but "get the file names alone" was part of an idea how to solve the problem suboptimally ;) This answer is also the only one as far as I can see that doesn't require external tools, quotes properly, doesn't break for filenames with special characters, doesn't remove the wrong stuff... good job.

Comment: I got it.. thank u

Comment: The second one is very good & faster than my expectation...

Comment: Hi , can u please explain the functionality of "${i%.*}" this? 
Means how it will detect the exact character in a string where we want to split?

Comment: @sivakarthik I've updated my answer to explain it

Comment: @JoseKilo yup i've gone through the updated answer.. It sounds good & easy to understand... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`prename`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) (installed together with the perl package on ubuntu).
Then you can just do something like:

```
prename 's/\.x$//' *.sh.x
```

Comment: I got it.. thank u

Answer (score 0):

In ksh you can do this:

```
for $file in $(ls $path)
do
    new_file=$(basename $path/$file .x)
    mv ${path}/${file} ${path}/${new_file}   
done
```

Comment: I got answer.. thank u

Answer (score 0):

Running this rename command from the root directory should work:

```
rename 's/\.sh\.x$/.sh/' *.sh.x
```

Comment: File `abshcx.sh.x` will be renamed to `a.sh.sh.x`...

Comment: I got it.. thank u

Comment: Thanks anishsane. Updated the answer.

Comment: Now, File `ab.sh.x.c.sh.x` will be renamed to `ab.sh.c.sh.x ` :-) You forgot to add `$` in the match string regex...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for file in *.sh.x; 
do 
   mv "$file " "${file /.sh.x}"; 
done
```

Comment: This removes `.sh.x` instead of just `.x`, and it doesn't make sure that the string being removed is at the end of the filename.

Comment: I got it.. thank u

Answer (score -1):

for i in `ls -la /path|grep -v ^d|awk '{print $NF}'`

do

echo "`basename $i`"
done

## it will give u the base name of all files or you can try below

find /path -type f -exec basename {} \;

Comment: Before answer plz, read it first. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Downvote: The advice is as atrocious as the formatting.